# Rails logger tags stays permanent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

When using Active Support Tagged Logging in Rails 7.0.4 the tag stays permanent. It looks like weird behavior. The documentation suggests that using `tagged` should only apply to current message but maybe I wrongly interpret the wording.

Also, the flush method (which seems to clear tag list) isn't working either.

My tests in rails console:

```
3.1.2 :027 > Rails.logger.tagged( "ThisIsTag" ).info( "ThisIsMessage" )
[ThisIsTag] ThisIsMessage
 => 26
3.1.2 :028 > Rails.logger.info( "ThisIsMessage" )
[ThisIsTag] ThisIsMessage
 => 14
3.1.2 :029 > Rails.logger.flush
 => nil
3.1.2 :030 > Rails.logger.info( "ThisIsMessage" )
[ThisIsTag] ThisIsMessage
 => 14
3.1.2 :031 > Rails.logger.tagged.info( "ThisIsMessage" )
ThisIsMessage
 => 14
3.1.2 :032 > Rails.logger.info( "ThisIsMessage" )
ThisIsMessage
 => 14
```

Looks like when applying tag to one message all of the following logs will have the same tag! It's so bizarre. I found out the only way of clearing the tag is calling `tagged` with no parameter. But then, using this in code is actually quite frankly annoying, the example:

```
def foo
  # some code
  Rails.logger.tagged( "Debug 123" ).debug( "Important debug message" )
  Rails.logger.tagged
  # some more code
end
```

So my question is: Does it work as expected? How the tags should be use in real life situations? Maybe I misuse the functionality, but to my understanding, I use them correctly and accordingly to the intention.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug.

If you run your examples in Rails 7.0, you will see that it only affects the output that is broadcast to the console.  But if you look at the log file, the tagging won't persist across logged messages.  For example, if you do:

```rb
Rails.logger.tagged('MyTag').info('Message1')
[MyTag] Message1
Rails.logger.info('Message2')
[MyTag] Message2
```

Then `log/development.log` will correctly only apply the tag to "Message1":

```
[MyTag] Message1
Message2
```

The behavior you are describing is also noted in [this open issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48787#issuecomment-1700352594).  I think [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/46084) is also related.

In Rails 7.1, by default the logging output isn't broadcast to the console. So you wouldn't see this behavior unless you tried to broadcast the logging somewhere else.

Comment: I used console just for tests purposes to show the issue. Actually, for me tags are visible in the logs. Both of the running server and in `log/production.log` which I later output to AWS CloudWatch. However, I do use lograge for production so maybe broadcasting loggers works differently. 

I did have notice the issue with tags because it is populated to the logs :) Thanks for linking the issue, it looks like exactly issue I encountered.